# Hide nearly all page elements except when user is site admin

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, javascript, jquery, css

I'm feeling my way through being a site collection admin. I have a home page I wish to remove all sharepoint elements and just have a table of buttons.
I've done this by added this CSS to a CEWP:

```
<style>

#welcomeMenuBox {
    display: none;
}

#globalNavBox { display: none; }

#suiteBarLeft {
    display: none;
}

#titleAreaBox {
    display: none;
}


#ms-help {
    display: none;
}

#RibbonContainer-TabRowRight {
    display: none;
}
/* Hide the BROWSE and PAGE Tabs */
.ms-cui-tts { display : none; }

.ms-breadcrumb-top {
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: none;
}

.ms-dialogHidden {
     display: none;
}
.ms-cui-topBar2 {
     display: none;
}
</style>
```

I wanted to limit this however so that non admins of the site see the stripped page and admins see everything. I thought I would do this by audience targetting the CEWPs for readers and then make another CEWP to hide that webpart for admins using this:

```
<style type="text/css">
#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2
{
    display:none !important;
}
</style>
```

This doesn't work as the CSS from the first webpart seems to bleed through.
I found online that this code can help:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        if(_spPageContextInfo.isSiteAdmin){
            // show your element
        }
    });
</script>
```

So it checks if user is admin and performs an action, but I have no idea how to implement it here.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

i think you have already did all the home work to achieve your functionality.I can help you little bit here how you can combine Javascript and css together and implement it.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


        <script type="text/javascript">
                                   if(!_spPageContextInfo.isSiteAdmin){ //if user is not side admin then hide the controls

    // here you can hide these control using below code not directly using css in cewp

    $("#welcomeMenuBox").css({"display": "none"}); //if you have jquery loaded

        // if you dont want to use jquery then use below code to apply css to your div element

    document.getElementById("welcomeMenuBox").style.display = 'none';

                    }

            </script>
```

Hope it helps.

Edited i think you want to use only javascript

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
                                   if(!_spPageContextInfo.isSiteAdmin){ //if user is not side admin then hide the controls
              document.getElementById("welcomeMenuBox").style.display = 'none';

}
```

Comment: Thanks. I added this to the page in a script part and used the following (seems I can't past what I used, too many chars. Hmmmmm). Basically, it doesn't hide anything. When I log on as my guest account, everything is still present.

https://pastebin.com/d6Lccx7n

Comment: I saw your code it seems you want to use only javascript no jquery. <script type="text/javascript">
                               if(!_spPageContextInfo.isSiteAdmin){ //if user is not side admin then hide the controls
    // if you dont want to use jquery then use below code to apply css to your div element
document.getElementById("welcomeMenuBox").style.display = 'none'; .it should work i have tested also now. but I think if you refrence jquery in your CEWP then it will easy to apply the css and get the element by css also

                }

        </script>

Comment: I think I do want to use jquery, how do easily reference it?

Comment: <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script> you can add at top inside CEWP webpart. Edited the Answer with Jquery Refrence

Comment: Thanks again. I've added that and used the following https://pastebin.com/hNbssXXT
But it hides everything for everyone, admins included.

Comment: Please try to debug in chrome browser using developer Tool https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/ , whether in both type of user _spPageContextInfo.isSiteAdmin is getting true. isSiteAdmin means site collection Administrator of the site. this is about condition is getting true everytime you can verify in browser.hope it helps

Comment: This is now becoming something my brain just cannot do. I have no idea how to debug this. I use the developer tools (F12) but I have no idea what I am looking for or at. I just assumed the detect admin functionality would work, it doesn't seem to. It blocks everything for everyone, readers and admins alike.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a security trimmed control to restrict certain things by permission level.

```
<Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl runat="server" Permissions="ManageWeb">
      Place your control(s), HTML, CSS, script, etc. here
</SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
```

Under `Permissions`, `ManageWeb` is the permission level that...

"Grants the ability to perform all administration tasks for the Web site as well as manage content. Activate, deactivate, or edit properties of Web site scoped Features through the object model or through the user interface (UI). When granted on the root Web site of a site collection, activate, deactivate, or edit properties of site collection scoped Features through the object model. To browse to the Site Collection Features page and activate or deactivate site collection scoped Features through the UI, you must be a site collection administrator."

You also have `FullMask`:

"Has all permissions on the Web site. Not available through the user interface."

For your case, you could combine a higher permission level with a lower level, like `ViewListItems`, to create CSS that hides the elements for all users and then re-shows for users with admin level permissions. Like so:

```
<Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl runat="server" Permissions="ViewListItems">
    <!-- OR LINK TO A CSS FILE -->
    <style>
    #welcomeMenuBox,
    #globalNavBox,
    #suiteBarLeft,
    #titleAreaBox,
    #ms-help,
    #RibbonContainer-TabRowRight,
    .ms-cui-tts,
    .ms-breadcrumb-top,
    .ms-dialogHidden,
    .ms-cui-topBar2 {
         display: none;
    }
    </style>
</SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>

<Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl runat="server" Permissions="ManageWeb">
    <!-- OR LINK TO A CSS FILE -->
    <style>
    #welcomeMenuBox,
    #globalNavBox,
    #suiteBarLeft,
    #titleAreaBox,
    #ms-help,
    #RibbonContainer-TabRowRight,
    .ms-cui-tts,
    .ms-breadcrumb-top,
    .ms-dialogHidden,
    .ms-cui-topBar2 {
         display: initial;
    }
    </style>
</SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
```

Here is a full list of possible members that you can use for `Permissions`. I would provide a link but I think MSFT has removed the resource. :-(

**EmptyMask** Has no permissions on the Web site. Not available through the user interface.

**ViewListItems** View items in lists, documents in document libraries, and view Web discussion comments.

**AddListItems** Add items to lists, add documents to document libraries, and add Web discussion comments.

**EditListItems** Edit items in lists, edit documents in document libraries, edit Web discussion comments in documents, and customize Web Part Pages in document libraries.

**DeleteListItems** Delete items from a list, documents from a document library, and Web discussion comments in documents.

**ApproveItems** Approve a minor version of a list item or document.

**OpenItems** View the source of documents with server-side file handlers.

**ViewVersions** View past versions of a list item or document.

**DeleteVersions** Delete past versions of a list item or document.

**CancelCheckout** Discard or check in a document which is checked out to another user.

**ManagePersonalViews** Create, change, and delete personal views of lists.

**ManageLists** Create and delete lists, add or remove columns in a list, and add or remove public views of a list.

**ViewFormPages** View forms, views, and application pages, and enumerate lists.

**AnonymousSearchAccessList** Make content of a list or document library retrieveable for anonymous users through SharePoint search. The list permissions in the site do not change.

**Open** Allow users to open a Web site, list, or folder to access items inside that container.

**ViewPages** View pages in a Web site.

**AddAndCustomizePages** Add, change, or delete HTML pages or Web Part Pages, and edit the Web site using a SharePoint Foundation–compatible editor.

**ApplyThemeAndBorder** Apply a theme or borders to the entire Web site.

**ApplyStyleSheets** Apply a style sheet (.css file) to the Web site.

**ViewUsageData** View reports on Web site usage.

**CreateSSCSite** Create a Web site using Self-Service Site Creation.

**ManageSubwebs** Create subsites such as team sites, Meeting Workspace sites, and Document Workspace sites.

**CreateGroups** Create a group of users that can be used anywhere within the site collection.

**ManagePermissions** Create and change permission levels on the Web site and assign permissions to users and groups.

**BrowseDirectories** Enumerate files and folders in a Web site using Microsoft Office SharePoint Designer 2007 and WebDAV interfaces.

**BrowseUserInfo**
View information about users of the Web site.

**AddDelPrivateWebParts**
Add or remove personal Web Parts on a Web Part Page.

**UpdatePersonalWebParts**
Update Web Parts to display personalized information.

**ManageWeb**
Grant the ability to perform all administration tasks for the Web site as well as manage content. Activate, deactivate, or edit properties of Web site scoped Features through the object model or through the user interface (UI). When granted on the root Web site of a site collection, activate, deactivate, or edit properties of site collection scoped Features through the object model. To browse to the Site Collection Features page and activate or deactivate site collection scoped Features through the UI, you must be a site collection administrator.

**AnonymousSearchAccessWebLists**
Content of lists and document libraries in the Web site will be retrieveable for anonymous users through SharePoint search if the list or document library has AnonymousSearchAccessList set.

**UseClientIntegration**
Use features that launch client applications; otherwise, users must work on documents locally and upload changes.

**UseRemoteAPIs**
Use SOAP, WebDAV, or Microsoft Office SharePoint Designer 2007 interfaces to access the Web site.

**ManageAlerts**
Manage alerts for all users of the Web site.

**CreateAlerts**
Create e-mail alerts.

**EditMyUserInfo**
Allows a user to change his or her user information, such as adding a picture.

**EnumeratePermissions**
Enumerate permissions on the Web site, list, folder, document, or list item.

**FullMask**
Has all permissions on the Web site. Not available through the user interface.